# Non-alphanumeric Characters sets not working

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, localizable.strings, xliff

I'm working to localize an app. I have my english xliff file that was translated. When I import the es.xliff (spanish) I get Localizable.strings (Spanish) and I can flip the app to Spanish, same with French.

For some reason with languages like Korean and Arabic ko.xliff and ar.xliff this is not working and I not getting a Localizable.strings file for this languages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to have the files in separate folders and choose them individually.

Comment: Would you mind marking your answer as accepted to make it appear that a solution has been found out, please?  